# Adjust window scrolling speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've been looking all over, but cannot seem to find any ways as to how I can achieve this, so here goes. I'm trying to adjust the scrolling speed to deviate from the browser's default speed. So the scrolling would be faster/slower than it normally would be.

I tried doing stuff with `$(window).scrollLeft()` but that isn't quite working for me. Does anybody know any way to do this in Javascript or jQuery?

Thanks :)

**Note**: I am not looking for the parallax effect ;)

Comment: Couple of links you might wanna look at: http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2007/08/08/df-javascript-smooth-scroll http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?209918-Help-Changing-the-scroll-speed-of-this-smooth-scroll-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick JavaScript class I threw together "AugmentScroll". In you window onload/document ready event just instance the class and it'll change the scrolling behavior. It uses an interval timer and the window scroll event. Hopefully this will get you started. It works in the latest Chrome and FF as well as IE9. The "smooth scrolling" Advanced / General option in FF manages to mess it up a bit.

```
window.onload = function() {

function AugmentScroll(type /* slowest|slower|slow|fast|faster|fastest */) {
    this.oldX = window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || 0;
    this.oldY = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
    this.deltaX = 0;
    this.deltaY = 0;
    this.busy = false;
    this.multiplier = 0;
    switch(type) {
        case 'slowest': this.multiplier = -0.9; break;
        case 'slower': this.multiplier = -0.5; break;
        case 'slow': this.multiplier = -0.2; break;
        case 'fast': this.multiplier = 0.2; break;
        case 'faster': this.multiplier = 0.5; break;
        case 'fastest': this.multiplier = 1.0; break;
        case '2x': this.multiplier = 1.0; break;
        case '3x': this.multiplier = 2.0; break;
        case '4x': this.multiplier = 3.0; break;
        case '5x': this.multiplier = 4.0; break;
        default: break;
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.OnScroll.bind(this), false);
    window.setInterval(this.OnUpdate.bind(this), 100);
};
AugmentScroll.prototype.OnScroll = function() {
    if(this.busy) {
        this.busy = false;
    } else {
        var x = window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || 0;
        var y = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
        this.deltaX = x - this.oldX;
        this.deltaY = y - this.oldY;
    }
    return true;
};  
AugmentScroll.prototype.OnUpdate = function() {
    var dx = this.deltaX * this.multiplier;
    var dy = this.deltaY * this.multiplier;
    if(dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        this.busy = true;
        window.scrollBy(dx, dy);
        this.oldX = window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || 0;
        this.oldY = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
        this.busy = false;
    }
};
new AugmentScroll('slowest');

};
```

Comment: Woah. That's amazing @LastCoder! It is quite laggy (might be due to my own code conflicting), but I'll crack my head and see whether I can work from this. I'm just a JS beginner.

Comment: @AKG - Start by lowering the interval time in "window.setInterval(this.OnUpdate.bind(this), 100)" the 100ms might be too large put it down to ~20ms and see if that can smooth it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cancel or alter the window scroll event. What you can try is getting the current scroll position and subtract a few pixel then set that as the scroll position. I don't suggest doing anything like this.

Comment: Rob, please take this in the right way. Unless your 'I don't suggest doing anything like this.' is aimed at your own answer to adjusting the scroll speed then please remove it from your comment. There are many reasons why @akg or anyone else might want to adjust window scrolling speed and the only part they asked help for was how to achieve it, not if you dont suggest doing it. If it was aimed at your own suggestion please make it clear and add some perspective why not. These boards are full of 'suggestions' most of which are utter tripe. Just answer the question and leave it at that.